# Change value of a cell if it starts with a specific number and make a CSV file

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a sub that generates a new student ID for every student where their Student ID starts with 262015. Their student ID is in column L. The new Student ID has to comply with the following requirements:

1. It has to start with 18 and has to end with FACULTY_ID for the student, each students FALCULTY_ID number is in column "I".
2. It has to be 8 characters long
3. The 5 numbers between 18 and the faculty_id has to be random.
4. It can only be numbers
5. It has to be unique.

This is the code i have so far i just need all of these requirements in my code. Hope someone can help :)

```
Sub newstudentid()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("L2:L18288")
For Each cell In Range
If Left(cell.Value, 6) = "262015" Then
```

And lastly i need to make a CSV file called AdminExport.csv for all of the affected students. The CSV file has to contain PERSON_ID, which is in column A, the old student_ID and the new one and Enroll_period which is in column E.

Comment: Any particular reason for using VBA? Seems like you could filter the sheet, copy/paste values into new sheet, use cell formula to create new IDs and save as CSV.

Comment: You say the new ID should be 8 characters long. it should start with 18. That is two characters. it should end with faculty_id which is five characters, that makes seven characters in total. And then it should be unique number but you only have one digit left to make unique. That makes only 10 students can exist.

Comment: Faculty_ID is only one character so there is five characters between 18 and the falculty_ID which has to be random and in total thats 8 characters

Comment: Ok. Why do you need them to be random? Why not start with 00001 etc.?

Comment: That is just one of the requirements for the sub :-)

Comment: I agree with@hughg, there is no need for VBA here (except to generate the unique random number). You can easily create a formula to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code?
Comments are in code.

```
Sub newstudentid()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("L2:L18288")
    For Each cell In rng
        If Left(cell.Value, 6) = "262015" Then
            ' start with 18 and faculty ID
            Start = "18"
            Faculty = cell.Offset(0, -3).Value

            'get a random number and format it to five digits
            random = Format(Application.RandBetween(0, 99999), "00000")

            'While the number exist in range
            ' CLng(Start & random & Facility) asumes the IDs are formated as numbers and not as strings
            While (Not IsError(Application.Match(CLng(Start & random), rng.Value, 0)))
                'create a new random number and format to five digits
                random = Format(Application.RandBetween(0, 99999), "00000")
            Wend

            'paste the new ID at cell.value
            cell.Value = Start & random & Faculty
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but It had to end with the faculty_id not start with it how should i change the code :)